# How to clean grill/coil of neglected dehumidifier that has hard lint / mold?

Tags: cleaning

I have Large DeLonghi PP50 and Frigidaire Brands in my home.
The grill and coils are very dirty

Comment: Will you please post some pictures? It would help a lot. Why is a vacuum cleaner + brush not good enough?

Comment: Hi user31398, Welcome to Lifehacks. When you get a chance, visit the [Tour] and [Help] to get the most from our site. Please use edit to add more information since you don't have enough points to comment.

Comment: I'd use a power washer

Comment: @CaiusJard The power washer might deliver water in places where water should not exist. Of course, it depends entirely on the particular device and the details of the problem. And the skills of whoever is doing the job :)

Comment: To echo virolino, a bottle brush or similar tool should be sufficient for most models, and it should be possible to dismantle enough of the dehumidifier to reach the coils (since these have to be relatively accessible in order to function), but it does depend on the design and exactly how inaccessible the coils are.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to get some baking soda, vinegar, and dish soap and mix them together into a spray preferably. Spray the whole surface with the mixture, and you should be able to wipe it off

Comment: Hi wilkvolk, Welcome to Lifehacks. When you get a chance, visit the [Tour] and [Help] to get the most from our site. Please use edit to add more information since you don't have enough points to comment. How do you get to the surfaces you cannot reach?